# gettign proxy of a bean in different project inside java class

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

I am new to the world of spring so i may ask a silly question but please let me the solution of my below problem please .

My problem is that I have two projects independent project nae is project A and project B ,now in project A i have the below xml configuration of bean

```
<bean id="abcService" class="com.jmx.JMXServiceImpl" autowire="no">
        <constructor-arg index="0">
            <ref bean="jobDetailsDomainHome" />
        </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

now in project A this bean get initilazied easily now i need this same bean initialized in project B also , so i have added project A in project B classpath also now please advise inside java class named rty of Project Bhow can i call this same bean abcService

Answer (score 0):

The bean `abcService` depends on bean `jobDetailsDomainHome`. So there's no way to use `abcService` without the other bean.

You can split the configuration in various xml files. So define the `abcService` and the needed beans in one xml file, which is imported by the configurations of project A and project B.

```
<import resource="classpath*:service-context.xml" />
```

The import of xml files can use the classpath like shown above. But you can use locations in the file system too.

It's not important which bean is defined in which file as long as every needed bean is defined.

Comment: so shall i import the xml that is there in project A into project B xmls directly

Comment: i am still not able to grasp classpath

Comment: I suggest 3 projects (projectA, projectB, projectService). In projectService you define the java classes and the bean definitions (service-context.xml) for the service. ProjectA and ProjectB use ServiceProject, so they have it in their classpath and that's why their import statements could use "classpath".